# Erroneous prediction of stock prices

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, stock

I have a code in Python that analyses historical data of Apple from Google Finance for the past 1 year. Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0uGb_yg04SEZUVFb0RHQ1hTUDg) to the data set. The code that I'm using is shown below:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

t=time.time()

dates=[]
prices=[]
f1=open('rbf.txt','wb')
f2=open('lin.txt','wb')
f3=open('poly.txt','wb')
def get_data(fname):
    with open(fname,'rb') as csvfile:
        csvFileReader=csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(csvFileReader)
        for row in csvFileReader:
            l=row[0].split()
            s=l[1].strip(',')
            dates.append(int(s))
            prices.append(float(row[1]))
    return

def predict_prices(dates,prices,x):
    dates=np.reshape(dates,(len(dates),1))

    svr_lin=SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
    svr_poly=SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=2)
    svr_rbf=SVR(kernel='rbf',C=1e3,gamma=0.1)
    svr_lin.fit(dates,prices)
    svr_poly.fit(dates,prices)
    svr_rbf.fit(dates,prices)

    f1.write(svr_rbf.predict(dates))
    print type(svr_rbf.predict(dates))
    print type(svr_rbf.predict(dates)[0])
    print type(svr_rbf.predict(dates)[0])
    f2.write(svr_lin.predict(dates))
    f3.write(svr_poly.predict(dates))
    '''
    plt.scatter(dates,prices,color='black',label='Data')
    plt.plot(dates,svr_rbf.predict(dates),color='red',label='RBF model')
    plt.plot(dates,svr_lin.predict(dates),color='green',label='Linear model')
    plt.plot(dates,svr_poly.predict(dates),color='blue',label='Polynomial model')
    plt.xlabel('Dates')
    plt.ylabel('Prices')
    plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    '''
    return svr_rbf.predict(x)[0],svr_lin.predict(x)[0],svr_poly.predict(x)[0]

get_data('aapl.csv')
predicted_price=predict_prices(dates,prices,6)
f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
print predicted_price
print time.time()-t
```

I need explanation for the final prediction values that are being returned by the system. The values that I am getting as output, are they the stock prices of the date that I have passed as a hard-coded parameter when I'm calling the prediction function or is it something else? If yes, the output that I'm getting is off by 35 points. The current data set is in the reverse order i.e. newest first. If I make it oldest first, will it then give me the right prediction? The reason for this analogy is that it's prediction comes out to be around 109 which was the stock's price 1 year back which is also the stock value in the last row of the file that has 1 year old date's data. How should I go about correcting it? Please point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance. The output that I'm getting for this is :

Comment: What is the data type of `dates`?

Comment: @VivekKumar dates and prices both are of data type list. BTW I tried reversing the list and then using it in the predict_prices function. It still gives the same prediction. Previous day open value was 138.8 but it shows today's prediction as 109.29. Is this error due to the small data set or something else?

Comment: `dates` is a list of ? (string, float etc)?? Also, just a single feature column and small dataset both attribute to wrong predictions. You can extract features from the date like, day of the week, day of month, etc, which may help

Comment: @VivekKumar It is a list of strings when it reads the values from csv file but in the predict_price function, the predict attribute of sklearn converts it into a numpy.ndarray and each element becomes numpy.float64. Also regarding your suggestion about having more features, I think you are right but will extracting getting the day of week and month be really helpful? As of now my feature column has only day of the month i.e for date 8th march, it extracts out 8 and the corresponding price. Should I keep 8 in a column, march in another column as 03(because march is the 3d month) and price last?

Comment: Yes. Also take day of the week (Mon, Tue...)

Comment: @VivekKumar Should I map weekday to numbers? For example Monday can be 1, Tuesday can be 2 and so on. Will that be the correct way?

Comment: That depends. You can either do that or do One-hot encoding. Try different things and see which one gives good results.

Comment: @VivekKumar For one-hot encoding, should I make 7 different columns for Mon, Tue and so on and then mark the column as 1 when it's necessary? For example, for 8th march, day_num column will be 8, month col will 3, Mon,Tue columns will be 0, Wed will be 1 and the remaining other columns will be 0 and the open price will be the last column. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. There are transformers available in scikit for this

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks a lot for your help! Really appreciate it. Will try this out and ask for your help again if it doesn't work out. But thanks again!

Comment: @VivekKumar As per your suggestion I am trying to add more parameters to this data set but how can I use it in my code? The fit function in sklearn library only accepts two parameters i.e. training parameter and target value. If I have to use month number and day, then I'll have to figure out a way to incorporate those values in my code as well. How should I do that with sklearn for the code mentioned above in the question? Thanks!

Comment: That training parameter you are talking about, can be an array of different features. Please see example documents how to use them

Comment: @VivekKumar Oh so you mean I'll be only passing one array as the training parameter but that array will be an array of arrays. Is that right? Also, if you have links to similar examples, please share. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes. You can have a look at simple dataset here - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-datasets-plot-iris-dataset-py

Comment: @VivekKumar Hi! I have prepared the data set just like you set. Using one hot encoding, I've made separate columns for months and weekdays. It was easy to do this using the pandas library or more specifically get_dummies function. My predict_prices function accepts 2 parameters, how should I pass so many features as a parameter to it then? Even if I take all the data and store it as an array of arrays, how will I do the computation inside the function? Please help or point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Now your data must have a shape of [n_samples, n_features]. ie. a single row contains data for single observation, (all the columns you made).

Comment: @VivekKumar Yes exactly! But how should I pass this data set in the predict function? Earlier the data set had only 2 columns - date and price. How should I code the other 16 parameters in the fucntion and pass them as parameters?

Comment: No. Just combine them all in a vector X (with shape [n_samples, n_features]), price should be your y (target), Then pass the X, y (only two parameters) into the function

Comment: @VivekKumar I'm not quite sure what combining means here. Do you mean I should just mkae it a 2D matrix? If I have 17 input paramters(excluding target parameter i.e. price) and say 200 samples, should I just make a 2D numpy array of the order 200x17? If yes, i can simply use numpy.vstack for the same and then transpose it, right? If not, please suggest a better method. Thanks!

Comment: yes. This is what I am saying. Also your prices (y) should be of shape [200,]

Comment: @VivekKumar The prices array will have the prices of each day so it will be a 1D array of size 200. Is this correct?

Comment: yes. that should be good to go

Comment: @VivekKumar Here's the link to my code : http://ideone.com/SG3XMc
On line 134, I have combined all data to get final input list named as features and prices is my target list. Now on line 43, I am passing the i/p, o/p and x as the function parameters. Earlier I had only one input parameter i.e. day number, so I used to pass that as x to the function. For example, if I wanted to predict for 8th day, I would pass input, output and 8 to the function. Now I have so many parameters to pass, so how should I modify my function? Please suggest relevant changes.

Comment: @VivekKumar Please let me know how this can be done. I just need to figure out a way to pass the array of arrays that I have created into the prediction function and pass parameters that I am using. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @VivekKumar I am passing the required parameters by storing them in a list and passing the list as the third parameter in the predict function. The code runs but gives no output at all. Can you please explain why nothing is getting returned? Also, the last line of the prediction function :
return svr_rbf.predict(x)[0],svr_lin.predict(x)[0],svr_poly.predict(x)[0]
Why are returning predict(x)[0] and not just predict(x)? Please explain.

Comment: What do you mean by "I wanted to predict for 8th day"?

Comment: @VivekKumar By 8th day I meant that I was accepting day number of the month(1,2,3,4.....30,31) as a parameter for which I would predict the corresponding price. Now I am passing the array of arrays having all parameters, the target parameter and a list where I hard-coded values of all parameters. The list that I pass as x in the prediction function is hard-coded like this : x=[3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]. I am passing this along with the array of arrays and prices. The code runs but gives no error and no output at all. What am I doing wrong here? I hope you have understood my point.

Comment: @VivekKumar Please suggest a way to solve this problem. After I pass the parameters in an array of arrays, the code runs successfully in about 160 second sbut gives no output. How can I fix this?